# Top js library to work with data model and ajax?

Tags: ajax, javascript

we are working on new project using Reactjs. We drop all oldschool libs like jquery and keep just simple React with some polyfills and small 3rd party libs. It works like a charm, it is small and fast.

But now we want to integrate some logic around backend models. I am not sure how to handle that.

First question:

What is currently "best" or most using ajax library? I check some like `fetch`, `superagent` and I am not sure if they are verified and production ready.

Send one:

For example model represent `User` entity. I want to cover basic REST ajax calls and custom ones `find`, `findAll`, `create`, `update`, `destroy`, or custom `toggleFollow`. And it should know about model logic like `fullName = function() {return firstName + " " + lastName}`. It is not hard to write by myself, but there is so many catches to handle. And it should be flux or flux-like compatible :)

Any suggestions, what is today popular and "in"?

Thanks